# How to write only 1 csv file and not multiple with python

Tags: python, export-to-csv

I am having an issue finding documentation on writing to the same file through multiple days(Sorry for not using the proper wordage). Right now it opens and writes to 1 csv file per day(which at this time is about 60 seperate files for 1 day). Instead I would like all 60 days of iteration to save to 1 file. I thought the "a" stood for append which means to write to the same file but that is not accurate I am finding. I also commented out the `outfile.close` at the end thinking that was why. The end goal is to have everyday saved in 1 file with only 1 header.

**SCRIPT:**

```
import csv
import requests
import datetime
from pprint import pprint
import pendulum

start = pendulum.datetime(2018, 3, 29)
end = pendulum.today()
period = pendulum.period(start, end)

for dt in period.range('days'):
    the_date = dt.format('YYYYMMDD')

    outfile = open('Test_between_dates' + str(the_date) + '.csv',"a",newline='')
    writer = csv.writer(outfile)
    writer.writerow(["time","status",])

    req2 = requests.get('https://api-prod.sprtactn.co/web/v1/scoreboard/mlb?bookIds=21,1,55&date=' + str(the_date) + '') #' + str(the_date) + '
    odd = req2.json()['games']

    for info in odd[0:]:
        time = info['start_time']
        status = info['status']


        print(time, status)

        writer.writerow([time, status])

##    outfile.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`outfile = open('Test_between_dates' + str(the_date) + '.csv',"a",newline='')`

`outfile` is determined by `the_date` and therefore different every day.

Comment: That makes sense, how would I go about changing that?

Comment: Give `outfile` a constant name. For example, you could just remove the `str(the_date)` part, yielding `'Test_between_dates.csv'`.